# Fonts in WIndows 8 look different when they are displayed than those on preview

Tags: fonts, truetype

I've randomly chosen to display an installed exotic .ttf fonts,
**but** they look very different than those on the preview:
"Kalam"

**EDIT**

Could someone give me a MWE how can I display them by their names "Kalam" and order number in the alphabet for XeTeX ?

[image]

**EDIT 2**
doesn't work well

[image]

Comment: preview _always_ uses the same (latin) characters. If they exists in the exotic fonts then you only see this one but not the "exotic" characters.

Comment: is this question related to the TeX typestting system?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Only via my 2 tags.

Comment: @user187802 So how can I display the characters themselves ?

Comment: so this is the wrong forum sorry the fonts tag is for use of fonts in Tex,.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So can you please give me a MWE how can I display them by their names "Kalam" for XeTeX ?

Comment: oh if you edited the question to ask that then it's definitely on topic and I'd remove the close vote

Comment: I dont seem to have a font `Kalam` in windows?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe that I have installed them though I'm not aware of it now.

Comment: seems to be available in google fonts, you should be able to use `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Kalam-Regular.ttf}`  if the font is installed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I type a particular letter ? When I intended a translation with latin letters it doesn't work: see my **EDIT 2**.

Comment: don't post code as an image, it is impossible to debug, but your output looks OK what do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant that the letters are not hieroglyphic like `kalam jemne` a `kalam normalni` as in the picture from the first snippet in my question.